# AngularJS dynamic form with drag and drop

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, drag-and-drop

I want to build a dynamic drag and drop form using angularJs.
this application will have `Buttons, images, p, div`. i need to drag elements from a tool box to drop html and i need to preview this page.

can any one help me which will be the better plugin for drag and drop in angularJs. i have found some of the plugins, but i need your help for better plugins if any and examples.

1. http://codef0rmer.github.io/angular-dragdrop/#!/
2. https://codepen.io/thinhlam/pen/BowEPp
3. https://github.com/Lane/angular-drag-and-drop
4. http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngDraggable

`AngularJS` Drag and Drop plugins and examples

Comment: See this one which is very good https://github.com/bevacqua/angularjs-dragula

Comment: @Zooly is this plugin will good for image ?

Comment: do you have any coding example for this plugin ?

Comment: Please look at the Readme on this Github repository, it shows the usage of this lib, and there's link for documentation

Comment: I used ngDraggable. its easy use.this is sample link  http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/fatlinesofcode/ngDraggable/blob/master/example.html

Comment: @Lakmi can you please post some code for this plugin

Comment: go to this link http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngDraggable then there is download option.they provide sample project